# I want delete one field that mi table but I dont want to make that

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
    db.users("user")
    .find()
    .forEach((elm) => {

        if(elm.name === 'john'){
            elm.pop();
        }else {
            print("Nothing to deleted")
        }
    });
```

The code said elm.pop() is not a function, I try with deleted, remove...any idea??

Thanks for all!

Comment: Add a `.filter(elm => elm.name !== 'john')` before the forEach.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! not found, this say is not a function

Comment: you are using the .pop method for an object instead you can use this
        if(elm.name === 'john'){
            delete elm
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant't understand what you are trying to do here ,
I hope this may work

**if you want to return all the document which name is not equal to "john"**

> https://mongoplayground.net/p/sCNe6gnJLij

```
db.collection.find({
  name: {
    "$ne": "john"
  }
});
```

**if you want delete the documents which contains name as "john" then use**

```
db.collection.deleteMany({
  name: {
    "$ne": "john"
  }
});
```